# Unable to cast object of type

Tags: c#

i want to get the maximum number

so i did this code

```
 public int autoIncrement()
    {
        int no = 0;
        odbcCon.OpenCon();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX (CustomerCode) FROM TBLM_CUSTOMER",odbcCon.MainCon);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            if (!dr.IsDBNull(0)) {

                 no = Convert.ToInt32(dr);

            }

        }
        dr.Close();
        return no;

    }
```

but

```
no = Convert.ToInt32(dr);
```

says

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

how can i solve this ? please tell me

Comment: You're casting the reader itself - how about trying with field 0?

Comment: Unrelated to the question but: you'll want to change `if (dr.Read())` to `while (dr.Read())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the index `0` for `DataReader`:

```
no = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to convert your data reader to an integer.

Try this instead:

```
if (!dr.IsDBNull(0)) {
    no = dr.GetInt32(0);
}
```

Comment: it says "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: What is the data type of CustomerCode in the SQL table? Your select statement will return the highest value of that column. If that column's data type is not an integer then you can't use .GetInt32 to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the index:

```
no = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting GetSqlInt32 property

```
no = dr.GetSqlInt32(0);
```